# Does starting method names with "Do" conform to some kind of standard?

Tags: c#, standards

For some reason, a couple of members of my team habitually starts method names with "Do"

e.g.

```
public void DoReopenLeads()  
public void DoProcessBaloney()
```

Now, I'm a "learn on the job" kind of a guy and haven't had any formal code training, so I don't know whether this is an industry accepted coding standard.

To my mind, it seems a bit dumb, as all methods "Do" something or other...

Coding standards for our team doesn't cover how to name methods (other than saying what the function does in fairly clear English)

Comment: Why can't you learn on the job by asking your coworkers about this?

Comment: "Do", "Handle", "Execute", just coding conventions used by the company

Comment: Does your company have a coding conventions? You should probably ask that

Comment: @Zack - actually, I've been learning on the job ever since FORTRAN-77, just not had any formal training since college.  Asking implies I don't know squat and I'd rather be a bit more informed.

Comment: @Pete Asking these kind of questions to your co-workers does not, in any way, imply any technical ignorance from your side. Naming methods like this is purely conventional.

Comment: Stop with this learn on the job by asking someone. I can tell you learn by asking teacher, learn by reading documentation, learn by trying yourself. Asking coworkers is not always possible, because they have other things to do. Also they can be annoyed by your questions. The rule is:Methods should have verb or verb phrase names after that is personal preference ! Also the method name should be easy to understand.

Comment: It's common to start "processing" methods/subroutines with `Do` but I wouldn't call it ubiquitous. Unless you have some kind of expected pattern to conform to, I'd just say make your name descriptive enough that you can understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: This is definetly not "an industry accepted coding standard". In your examples this is just plain useless, since it doesn't add anything useful to the method name, only noise. It become even more useless if that is added to _every_ method.

Comment: There's no such c# convention.  [MS Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) only state *DO give methods names that are verbs or verb phrases.*  But there may be some company convention here, e.g. there might be many higher level methods `ProcessX()` which call `InitializeX()` then `DoX()` then `TerminateX()`.  So, ask your manager or other responsible person for guidance on company conventions, e.g. "I have noticed many methods named `DoX()`.  Is this a company convention, and if so, can you point out what conventions I should be following, please?"

Answer (score 3):

There are no such standard. Maybe this is local "style". Prefix "Do" can be useful if there are several methods/functions with same words after "Do" like: `PrepareProcess`, `LoadProcess`, `FinishProcess` - then `DoProcess` will be normal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no kind of definition that each method should start with "`Do`".

One principle from Clean Code (I love and recommend the book from Robert C. Martin) for naming methods is that **you should not look into a function in order to know what the function does**. So the naming has to transport the meaning.

Methods should be verbal phrases, because they actual "do" something with or on the data. But just beginning all method with a `Do` prefix only adds *useless* information. Being more *specific* makes it easier to accomplish the "Clean Code" goal.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for methods that represent actions method's name starts with a verb. “do” or “does” are auxiliary verbs and rarely they add meaning.

Btw, take a look at this: [C# Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this topic is kind of oponionated I would like to share some soft guidances I have found.

The DoFactorys [C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards) only states that:

> use noun or noun phrases to name a class

A rather useful guide of AvSol [C# Guideline](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/CSharpGuidelines/releases) maintained by Dennis Doomen states that:

> Name methods using a verb like `Show` or a verb-object pair such as `ShowDialog`. A good name should give a hint on the *what* of a member, and if possible, the *why*.
>
> Also don't include `And` in the name of a method. It implies that method is doing more than one thing, which violates the single responsibility principle...

In the end, the are no such official guidelines exist written in stone. Your workspace and domain culture should drive creating your own guidelines.

For a good start I suggest you to read [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) written by Eric Evans. It contains a section called [Ubiquitous Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) which might help you to learn how to create and evolve your shared language by closely consulting with your domain experts AND fellow coworkers. Your code could also follow this common language, so your codebase could tell "stories" or use-cases by reading it.

An other good reference about the UL is written by [Andrew Whitaker](https://www.peoplematter.com/blog/domain-driven-design-importance-ubiquitous-language), where he writes that:

> Having a ubiquitous language improves the coherence of the code base and keeps everyone on the same page.

Comment: Note that in author's examples, method names already start with verbs (Reopen, Process), so adding one more Do verb does nothing useful.